# How to append a list of text on graph dot labels

Tags: svg, d3.js

mya I ask how to label each dot on a line graph with their unified label? For example, in this example https://datawanderings.com/2019/11/01/tutorial-making-an-interactive-line-chart-in-d3-js-v-5/
I modified the code to add a text label "a" on top of each circle, by adding the code in line 136 as below:

```
var label = lines.selectAll("circles")
    .data(function(d) { return(d.values); } )
    .enter()

    label.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "bottom")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); })
    .text("a")
```

My output is like this
[image]

However, my real desired output is to add this existing list to label each three lines:

existing_list = [['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a14'],['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','b11','b12','b13','b14'],['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10','c11','c12','c13','c14']]

That's said, each label is different and the 5th label on line B should be labeled as 'b5'. May I ask how to achieve this?

The complete code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Multi Line Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
<script>
//------------------------1. PREPARATION------------------------//
//-----------------------------SVG------------------------------//
const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const margin = 5;
const padding = 5;
const adj = 30;
// we are appending SVG first
const svg = d3.select("div#container").append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "-"
          + adj + " -"
          + adj + " "
          + (width + adj *3) + " "
          + (height + adj*3))
    .style("padding", padding)
    .style("margin", margin)
    .classed("svg-content", true);

//-----------------------------DATA-----------------------------//
const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%Y");
const dataset = d3.csv("data.csv");
dataset.then(function(data) {
    var slices = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d){
                return {
                    date: timeConv(d.date),
                    measurement: +d[id]
                };
            })
        };
    });

//----------------------------SCALES----------------------------//
const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return timeConv(d.date)}));

yScale.domain([(0), d3.max(slices, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.measurement + 4; });
        })
    ]);

//-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
const yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .ticks((slices[0].values).length)
    .scale(yScale);

const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
    .scale(xScale);

//----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
const line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); });

let id = 0;
const ids = function () {
    return "line-"+id++;
}

//---------------------------TOOLTIP----------------------------//
const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .style("position", "absolute");

//-------------------------2. DRAWING---------------------------//
//-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xaxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(yaxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

//----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
const lines = svg.selectAll("lines")
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

lines.append("path")
    .attr("class", ids)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

lines.append("text")
    .attr("class","serie_label")
    .datum(function(d) {
        return {
            id: d.id,
            value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + (xScale(d.value.date) + 10)
            + "," + (yScale(d.value.measurement) + 5 )+ ")"; })
    .attr("x", 5)
    .text(function(d) { return ("Serie ") + d.id; });

//---------------------------POINTS-----------------------------//
lines.selectAll("points")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); })
    .attr("r", 1)
    .attr("class","point")
    .style("opacity", 1);

var list = [['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a14'],
['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','b11','b12','b13','b14'],
['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10','c11','c12','c13','c14']]
console.log(list)
//---------------------------EVENTS-----------------------------//
var label = lines.selectAll("circles")
    .data(function(d) { return(d.values); } )
    .enter()

    label.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "bottom")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); })
    .text("a")

    label.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        tooltip.transition()
            .delay(30)
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1);

        tooltip.html(d.measurement)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 25) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");

        const selection = d3.select(this).raise();

        selection
            .transition()
            .delay("20")
            .duration("200")
            .attr("r", 6)
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style("fill","#ed3700");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", 0);

        const selection = d3.select(this);

        selection
            .transition()
            .delay("20")
            .duration("200")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please post the additional codes that gives me detail of how you are rendering the lines. I have one or two solutions in mind.

Comment: Why wouldn't the labels not be part of the data?